# How to search for data in the sqLiteDatabase with multiple search items and one button?

Tags: android, string, cursor, android-sqlite

I have already an working app within Android Studio, but I want to update it. The update will be to search on two different types of data.

The app will let the user add a car by it license plate and/or chassis number, the car will be placed to a parking lot. The next step is to find the car back, for this the user can search for the car by (now) only the license plate. I want to change that so the user can search for the car by it license plate or chassis number. See code below for what I already have.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SearchCarData extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView DisplayParkinglot, DisplayLicensePlate, DisplayChassisNumber;
EditText SearchLicensePlateTxt;
MyDBHelper myDBHelper;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
String license_plate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_car_data_layout);
    SearchLicensePlateTxt = (EditText) 
findViewById(R.id.searchLicensePlateTxt);
    DisplayParkinglot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayParkingLot);
    DisplayLicensePlate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayLicencePlate);
    DisplayChassisNumber = (TextView) 
findViewById(R.id.displayChassisNumber);

    DisplayParkinglot.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    DisplayLicensePlate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    DisplayChassisNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public void searchCar(View view) {
    license_plate = SearchLicensePlateTxt.getText().toString();
    myDBHelper = new MyDBHelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = myDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = myDBHelper.getCarInfo(license_plate, sqLiteDatabase);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String PARKINGLOT = cursor.getString(0);
        String LICENSEPLATE = cursor.getString(1);
        String CHASSISNUMBER = cursor.getString(2);

        DisplayParkinglot.setText(PARKINGLOT);
        DisplayLicensePlate.setText(LICENSEPLATE);
        DisplayChassisNumber.setText(CHASSISNUMBER);

        DisplayParkinglot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        DisplayLicensePlate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        DisplayChassisNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

So I want to change the code to make it possible to search on license plate or chassis number. Has someone a tip or idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked it out, I have tried to add a new cursor to it and it worked.

```
public class SearchCarData extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView DisplayParkinglot, DisplayLicensePlate, DisplayChassisNumber;
EditText SearchTxt;
MyDBHelper myDBHelper;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
String license_plate, chassis_number;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_car_data_layout);
    SearchTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchTxt);
    DisplayParkinglot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayParkingLot);
    DisplayLicensePlate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayLicencePlate);
    DisplayChassisNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayChassisNumber);

    DisplayParkinglot.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    DisplayLicensePlate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    DisplayChassisNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public void searchCar(View view) {
    license_plate = SearchTxt.getText().toString();
    chassis_number = SearchTxt.getText().toString();
    myDBHelper = new MyDBHelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = myDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = myDBHelper.getCarInfo(license_plate, sqLiteDatabase);
    Cursor cursor1 = myDBHelper.getCarInfo2(chassis_number, sqLiteDatabase);
    //Search by License Plate
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String PARKINGLOT = cursor.getString(0);
        String LICENSEPLATE = cursor.getString(1);
        String CHASSISNUMBER = cursor.getString(2);

        DisplayParkinglot.setText(PARKINGLOT);
        DisplayLicensePlate.setText(LICENSEPLATE);
        DisplayChassisNumber.setText(CHASSISNUMBER);

        DisplayParkinglot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        DisplayLicensePlate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        DisplayChassisNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    //Search by Chassis Number
     else if (cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
         String PARKINGLOT = cursor1.getString(0);
         String LICENSEPLATE = cursor1.getString(1);
         String CHASSISNUMBER = cursor1.getString(2);

         DisplayParkinglot.setText(PARKINGLOT);
         DisplayLicensePlate.setText(LICENSEPLATE);
         DisplayChassisNumber.setText(CHASSISNUMBER);

         DisplayParkinglot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         DisplayLicensePlate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         DisplayChassisNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }
}
```

So thank you Suja for you help, that helped me to search better.

Answer (score 0):

When you query for data from db include both fields . If you are accessing db using content provider then your code may look something like this.

```
Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionargs, sortOrder);
```

in this the  *CONTENT_URI* points your table, *projection* defines your table columns , *selection* - the columns which you have data for, *selectionargs* - the data

hope it helps you

Comment: I was trying as you suggest, but it didn't worked for me. I copied your line and replaced it for the table, columns and so on. But then I get a red line. Maybe I did something wrong, so can you make a sample for me with my data?